# use Devart MyDac on android device

Tags: android, mysql, delphi, mydac

I are trying to use MyDac on my andriod delphi app but I keep running into a loss of vital information.

I need a file libmysqld.so in the application executable file location whish to me is $Plateform\debug folder of my project.

But I cannot find anywhere or any documentation on how to generate it or download it. I know with Win32/64 you get the libmysqld.dll file when you install MySql server.

Once I have the .so file where do I deploy it to as The device will need it for the app to run.

Im using delphi Berlin 10.1 and the latest version of MyDac

Comment: Set "Direct := True;" on your TMyConnection. Also, consider using UniDac as suggested in this Devart Blog http://blog.devart.com/android-database-application-development-in-rad-studio-xe5.html

Comment: So reading the blog. Quote "MySQL client software for Android also doesn’t exist, therefore connection to MySQL server will also be established directly via TCP/IP. For this, let’s set the corresponding option:" I cannot embedded a stand alone server into my app on an android. With MyDac